# Flex does not run the application, but rise an error?

Tags: apache-flex, frameworks

Recently i got this error

```
SecurityError: Error #2148: SWF file file:///C:/Users/SUN/Desktop/TriStateCheckBox2/bin-debug/index.swf cannot access local resource file:///C:/Users/SUN/Desktop/TriStateCheckBox2/bin-debug/framework_4.5.0.20967.swf. Only local-with-filesystem and trusted local SWF files may access local resources.
    at flash.net::URLStream/load()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/load()
    at mx.core::CrossDomainRSLItem/load()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\CrossDomainRSLItem.as:227]
    at mx.core::RSLListLoader/loadNext()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\RSLListLoader.as:184]
    at mx.core::RSLListLoader/load()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\RSLListLoader.as:156]
    at mx.preloaders::Preloader/initialize()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:297]
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::initialize()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2103]
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/initHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2588]
```

- The error goin when i cahnge "Framework linkage" to "Merge into the code", but it is anoing.
- Do someone have this issue, and how did he resolve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.flxsolutions.net/archives/75